# Semaphore implementation excercise (pseudocode)

Tags: c, synchronization, pseudocode, producer-consumer

Firstly, Merry Christmas all.

I would like to present here an excercise I'm working in and then give you a possible solution.

"A group of students is studying for an exam. The students only can study while they eat pizza. Moreover, if a student finds out there's no pizza, he/she sleeps till a new pizza arrives. The first student who finds that his/her group has no pizza calls a pizzeria to order another pizza before going to sleep. Each pizza has S slices. No slice of pizza can't be consumed by more than one student. Complete the code to synchronize and implement the two following threads, students() and pizza_delivery(). Your solution should avoid deadlocking, with variable and semaphore management".

We have to put our code in the commented sections below.

Consequently, my solution is as follows:

```
int slices=0;

//int i = 0;

//void Study();

//void makePizza();

//sem produce = 0;

//sem consume = 0;

Sem mutex=1;

bool first = true, havePizza = false;

students() {
    while(TRUE) {
        wait(mutex);
        while(!havePizza) {
            if(slices > 0) {
                slices--;
                havePizza = true;
            }
            else {
                if(first) {
                    //signal(mutex);
                    //signal(produce);
                    first = false;
                }
                //else {
                    //pause();
                    //}
            }
        }
        //wait(consume);
        //signal(mutex);
        Study();
        havePizza = false;
    }
}

pizza_delivery() {
    while(TRUE) {
        //wait(produce);
        //wait(mutex);
        makePizza();
        slices = S;
        first=true;
        //for (i = 0; i < S; i++) {
        //      signal(consume);
        //}
        signal(mutex);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something in this producer-consumer problem?
Any opinions about my code?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: There are some issues, for example:
while(!havePizza) {
    if(slices > 0) {
        slices--;
...
why would they eat pizza while they don't have pizza?, next:
slices--;
the -- operator is not always atomic so I would be careful here.
Also avoid naming semaphore "mutex", mutexes and semaphores are something very different, while I'm not an expert in mutli-threading this guy explains a similar problem here, and should help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6zkaJFjUbM&list=PLfqABt5AS4FmuQf70psXrsMLEDQXNkLq2&index=23.

Comment: Thank you a lot @JakubBednarski for your reply. Bear in mind that all but the commented lines come from the excercise's instructions. You can't touch them. I'll correct the code since I have new ideas. Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
int slices=0;

int i = 0; // Counter variable for the pizza slice consumption
           // n-ary semaphore

void Study(); // Function declaration for studying

void makePizza(); // Function declaration for making pizza

sem produce = 0; // Declaration of a binary semaphore for producing
                 // one pizza

sem consume = 0; // Declaration of a n-ary semaphore for consuming one 
                 // pizza

Sem mutex=1;

bool first = true, havePizza = false;

students() {
    while(TRUE) {
        wait(mutex);
        while(!havePizza) {
            if(slices > 0) {
                slices--;
                havePizza = true;
            }
            else {
                if(first) {
                    signal(mutex); // The thread students() gets out
                                   // of the critical section                    
                    signal(produce); // The first student who 
                                     // discovers they've run out of 
                                     // pizza, calls the pizzeria
                                     // The pizzeria is ready to 
                                     // produce one pizza                    
                    first = false;
                }
                else { // After calling the pizzeria
                      continue; // The students sleep till a pizza is 
                                // delivered
                     }
            }
        } // end while !HavePizza
        wait(consume); // Each student consumes one slice of pizza
        signal(mutex); // The thread students() gets out of the      
                       // critical section
        Study();
        havePizza = false;
    }
}

pizza_delivery() {
    while(TRUE) {
        wait(produce); // The pizzeria waits for the students' call
        wait(mutex); // The thread pizza_delivery() enters the 
                     // critical section
        makePizza(); 
        slices = S;
        first=true;
        for (i = 0; i < S; i++) { // The semaphore for consuming one 
                                  // pizza is incremented to S              
        signal(consume); // One pizza with S slices is ready to be 
                         // consumed
        }
        signal(mutex);
    }
}
```